# Cropping/Clipping Map

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arctoolbox

I'm using ArcGIS and my datasets cover most of the world, but I'm wanting to focus on just Iceland and I'm wondering how you crop the layers to a specific area?

I've read about the crop tool, but that uses a polygon as the 'cutting line' but how do I actually draw a graphic shape that can be used in such way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two possibilities:

- Crop layers in your dataframe with specific shape (you can also create a query def on polygon layer contain Iceland admin boundary area and use it)
- Clip all data with a polygon layer (for exemple use a countries boundary area layer and select specific country Iceland)

**For the fist solution look at this** :

- [Clip the data frame to make your map polished professional](http://www.esri.com/news/arcwatch/1012/clip-the-data-frame-to-make-your-map-polished-professional.html)
- [Clipping the Data Frame - ArcGIS Help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s90000000q000000)

**For the second method**:

- [Clip analysis - ArcGis Help](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/clip.htm)
- [Raster Processing/Clip](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/clip.htm)